# ionic 4 *ngFor wouldnt work at all in any project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

Ok so I am completely new to Ionic and Angular but what I am trying to do is very simple. Display the data that I am receiving to be displayed in an ion-card. I have created a service named "ActivityService" that holds the data.
my **app.module.ts** is:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, HttpClientModule,],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

My **activity.service.ts**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Activity } from './types';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ActivityService {

  constructor(private _httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getActivity(activityID : string): Observable<Activity>{
    return this._httpClient.get<Activity>(API +"/id/"+activityID);
  }

  getAllActivities(): Observable<Activity[]>{
    return this._httpClient.get<Activity[]>(API);
  }
}

const API = "http://orangevalleycaa.org/api/videos";
```

My **home.module.ts**:

```
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Tab1Page } from './tab1.page';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Activity } from '../types';
import { ActivityService } from '../activity.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([{ path: '', component: Tab1Page }])
  ],
  declarations: [Tab1Page]
})
export class Tab1PageModule {

  activityList: Observable<Activity[]>;

  constructor(activityService: ActivityService){
    this.activityList = activityService.getAllActivities();

  }
}
```

My **home.page.html**:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="danger">
    <ion-title>
       Buttons
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-card *ngFor="let activity of (activityList | async)">

    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-subtitle>Destination</ion-card-subtitle>
      <ion-card-title>awdaww</ion-card-title>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      Founded in 1829 on an isthmus between Lake Monona and Lake Mendota, Madison was named the capital of the Wisconsin Territory in 1836.
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

**Note**: The problem is that *ngFor is not working in any case. Also, as you can see, I have a console.log there as well to display that the data is being received and it sure is. But no matter what i do, *ngFor doesnt work in any way or case. I have tried simple ways to display data. Which is still not working.

My **home.module.ts**:

```
  cryptoList: string[] = [
    "Bitcoin",
    "Ethereum",
    "Bitcoin Cash",
    "Ripple",
    "Litecoin"
  ];
  constructor( ) {
  }
```

My **home.page.html**:

```
<ion-item>
      <ion-label>Cryptocurrency</ion-label>
      <ion-select>
        <ion-select-option *ngFor="let crypto of cryptoList" [value]="crypto">{{ crypto }}</ion-select-option>
      </ion-select>
 </ion-item>
```

I still get nothing.

**IONIC INFO**:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.1
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.10.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : none
   Cordova Plugins   : no whitelisted plugins (0 plugins total)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 0.2.8
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `home.module.ts`, you're subscribing to the `Observable` returned by `activityService.getAllActivities()`.

But in the template, you're still using an `async` pipe.

You'd do either one of those but not both.

So either `subscribe` to the `Observable`. Or use the `async` pipe in the template.

But don't do both because the `async` pipe doesn't work with normal JavaScript objects and subscribing to the `Observable` returned by `activityService.getAllActivities()` would unwrap the `Observable`.

I'd suggest just using the `async` pipe in the template. So get rid of this line:

```
this.activityList.subscribe((response) => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

From the `constructor` of `HomePageModule`.

Comment: hello. kindly note that I added subscribe AFTER the issue started happening to see whether i am even receiving the data or not. I again, removed the .subscribe and still it isnt working with async not in any other way. Is it possible that my version of ionic might be having some kind of problem? that they may have changed things into it? I am not sure because @Orbit's mentioned link shows a completely different files managment of the project. I am not sure why is that.

Also, not that no other kind of ngFor is working either. look at my other example as well. The simpler one.

Comment: Would it be possible to create a minimal verifiable [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/ionic) example replicating the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here is working [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-gtzhj2?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

I think this is the place wrong which you are doing

```
console.log(this.activityList[0]):
//assign this
this.cryptoList=this.activityList[0];
```